# How can I show that the following is the limit of the sequence of functions.

Tags: real-analysis

I have a sequence of functions $f_n(x)=x^n$ defined on the interval $[0, 1]$. How can I show that this sequence converges pointwise to $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if}\, x \in [0, 1) \\
1 &\text{if}\, x=1
\end{cases} $$

Obviously, I have to show there is some $N$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$. However, the limiting function being defined in the way that it is is giving me confusion.

Comment: You seem to be  getting your quantifiers in the wrong order. At best the sentence starting "Obviously" is ambiguous. You should fix $x$. There are two cases (a)$x=1$ (b) $x\ne 1$. Case (a) is clear. Case (b), that $x^n\to 0$, is pretty trivial,

Comment: @ancientmathematician: Thank you so much. This clears up the difficulty for me and now I can complete the proof.

Comment: Great! To practice some of the relevant terminology, it sounds like you were attempting to prove that the sequence of functions converges *uniformly* (which it doesn't), when actually you only have to prove that the sequence of functions converges *pointwise*.